# IE10 Dropdown CSS Not Working

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown menu that is activated with a CSS hover. But IE is not doing the hover command. I have tried just setting the drop down menu to appear without a hover, and that works, but no `:hover` on the li will do anything.

HTML:

```
            <div id="pilatesNav">
                <ul>
                    <li id="first" class="first mainNav"><a href="studio"><p>Studio</p></a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="etiquette"><p>Etiquette</p></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="mainNav"><a href="about"><p>About</p></a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="instructors"><p>Instructors</p></a></li>
                            <li><a href="testimonials"><p>Testimonials</p></a></li>
                            <li><a href="community"><p>Community</p></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="mainNav"><a href="classes"><p>Classes</p></a></li>
                    <li class="mainNav"><a href="beginners"><p>Beginners</p></a></li>
                    <li class="mainNav"><a href="schedule"><p>Schedule</p></a></li>
                    <li class="mainNav"><a href="videos"><p>Videos</p></a></li>
                    <li class="last mainNav"><a href="contact"><p>Contact</p></a></li>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

CSS

```
#pilatesNav{
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        overflow: visible;

        ul{
            list-style-type: none;
            overflow: visible;


            li{
                position: relative;
                text-align: center;
                z-index: 2;
                float: left;
                margin-right:85px;
                overflow: visible;

                a{
                    display: block;
                    color: #666;

                    &:hover{
                        color: lighten(@bg, 20%); 
                    }
                }
                ul{
                    position: absolute;
                    left: -9999px;
                    width: 137px;
                    text-align: center;
                    list-style-type: none;
                    background-color: @bg;
                    border-left: 1px solid darken(@bg, 10%);
                    border-right: 1px solid darken(@bg, 10%);
                    border-bottom: 1px solid darken(@bg, 10%);
                    .drop-shadow(0px, 6px, 5px, -7px, #111, 50%);

                    li{
                        display: block;
                        a{
                            display: block;
                        }
                        width: 100%;
                        padding: 5px 0px;
                        &:hover{
                            a{
                                color: lighten(@bg, 20%);
                            }
                            &:before{
                                width: 0;
                                height: 0;
                            }
                            .gradient(@bg, darken(@bg, 6%), @bg);
                        }
                    }
                }
                &:hover{
                    &:before{
                        position: absolute;
                        left: -15px;
                        content: '';
                        height: 25px;
                        width: 5px;
                        background-color: transparent;
                        border-left: 1px solid darken(@bg, 10%);
                    }
                    ul{
                        left: -15px;
                    }
                }
                &.first{
                    text-align: left;
                }
                &.last{
                    margin-right: 0px;
                    text-align: right;
                }
            }
        }
    }//End Nav
```

Comment: This is a long shot, but what is your doctype decleration?

Comment: @napo190 Haha, you know what? While I was deleting code to find interfering code, I found somehow I had two doctypes and the first wasn't even finished. Deleted the extra doctype and bam, it worked. Find it funny only IE gets broken over a doctype.

Put that as an answer and I will accept it! Thank you.

Comment: What I do sometimes to check for any errors is run the site in Chrome. Do you use the developer tools at all? Its great because it will pickup any errors or warnings. In your case, I bet chrome would have picked up the duplicate doctype decleration and given you a warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your doctype declaration.

I had troubles in a website that we had that worked in IE9 but not in IE10, had to change to the standard `<DOCTYPE !html>` Also, just to be safe confirm that all of your doctype declarations are correct and not duplicated.